# How to disable the window that pops up after neural network training in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, neural-network, nntool

I am relatively new to MATLAB Neural Netowrks, I'm using the network for some function approximation while another code is running and I'll be training the neural network for several times in just one run. After the training is done, a window pops up showing general information about the network and the training process, how can I disable that window so that it won't pop up anymore?

Comment: Where is the line that create the new figure ? Inside the built-in function or in your code ? We need more info.

Comment: inside the built in function. Finn answered it, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command you are looking for is:

```
Net.trainParam.showWindow = false;
```

if you dont want the window as it interrupts the progress, but still want some information about your net you might should go for:

```
Net.trainParam.showCommandLine = true;
```

'Net' being your net in this case. And for future questions please mention that it is the MATLAB 'Neural Network Toolbox' you are using

Comment: thanks that did the job. 
ok, will do. sorry for any inconvenience i may have caused

Answer (score 0):

Disable the 'Plots','training-progress' option